# SAXON 6.5.4 from Michael Kay adding %20

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

This will replace the spaces on the output path with a %20

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -jar  ./saxon.jar -o 'test with space/out.xml'  'test with space/input.xml'  'test with space/transform.xml'

[saxon]$ ll
total 558
saxon.jar
test%20with%20space        <---------
test with space

However when running with JAVA 1.4.2_22 it works just fine and does not a....
saxon.jar
test with space          <--------- :)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Haven't seen Java 1.4 for a while! And this is a very old Saxon release also. The current version does what you expect, of writing a filename with spaces. However, it's not at all clear-cut, there's a lot of messiness in this area, because XSLT deals in URIs rather than filenames, and URIs can't contain spaces.

Comment: Is there a parameter value I can pass to saxon 6.5.4 so it won't replace spaces with %20 when running with later version of java 1.4.2? and why would saxon behave different on newer java versions ?